# Intersection Observer in Typescript throws error in useRef

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, intersection-observer

I have here a text animation that is working perfect. What I want to add now is an Intersection Observer so that the animation only starts once I scroll down to the Box.

So what I did to achieve this is:
I used the react hook `useRef` to use as reference to the element I want to observe and applied it to my Box with `ref={containerRef}`. Then declared a callback function that receives an array of IntersectionObserverEntries as a parameter, inside this function I take the first and only entry and check if it is intersecting with the viewport and if it is then it calls setIsVisible with the value of entry.isIntersecting (true/false). After that I added the react hook useEffect and created an observer contructor using the callback function and the options I just created before. I implemented the logic in a new hook that I called `useElementOnscreen`

But Typescript is telling me an error at `containerRef?.current`:

```
Argument of type 'IntersectionObserver' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'.
  Type 'IntersectionObserver' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': attributes, classList, className, clientHeight, and 160 more.
```

And I am not sure how to solve this error. I think this is also the reason that my `ref={containerRef}` is throwing an error too

```
The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { component: ElementType<any>; } & SystemProps<Theme> & { children?: ReactNode; component?: ElementType<...> | undefined; ref?: Ref<...> | undefined; sx?: SxProps<...> | undefined; } & CommonProps & Omit<...>'
```

**The animation:**
So, TopAnimateBlock and BottomAnimateBlock have numOfLine property hence how many lines is inside the block. The second property in BottomAnimateBlock is delayTopLine, it should have the same numbers as a numOfLine in TopAnimateBlock, because we need to wait for top lines to play.

`TextAnimation.tsx`

```
import { Box, Stack, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';

const showTopText = keyframes`
  0% { transform: translate3d(0, 100% , 0); }
  40%, 60% { transform: translate3d(0, 50%, 0); }
  100% { transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
`;
const showBottomText = keyframes`
  0% { transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0); }
  100% { transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
`;

const Section = styled.section`
  width: calc(100% + 10vmin);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  padding: 2vmin 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  &:last-child {
    border-top: 1vmin solid white;
  }
`;

const Block = styled.div<{ numOfLine: number }>`
  position: relative;
`;
const TopAnimateBlock = styled(Block)`
  animation: ${showTopText} calc(0.5s * ${props => props.numOfLine}) forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  transform: translateY(calc(100% * ${props => props.numOfLine}));
`;
const BottomAnimateBlock = styled(Block)<{ delayTopLine: number }>`
  animation: ${showBottomText} calc(0.5s * ${props => props.numOfLine}) forwards;
  animation-delay: calc(0.7s * ${props => props.delayTopLine});
  transform: translateY(calc(-100% * ${props => props.numOfLine}));
`;

const TextStyle = styled.p<{ color: string }>`
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12vmin;
  color: ${props => props.color};
`;


const useElementOnScreen = (options) => {
    const containerRef = useRef<IntersectionObserver | null>(null);
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

    const callbackFunction = (entries) => {
        const [entry] = entries;
        setIsVisible(entry.isIntersecting);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callbackFunction, options);

        if (containerRef.current) observer.observe(containerRef?.current);

        return () => {
            if (containerRef.current) observer.unobserve(containerRef?.current);
        };
    }, [containerRef, options]);

    return [containerRef, isVisible];
};

export function Details() {
    const [containerRef, isVisible] = useElementOnScreen({
        root: null,
        rootMargin: '0px',
        threshold: 1.0,
    });

    return (
    <>
    <Typography>Scroll Down</Typography>
     <Box ref={containerRef}>
      <Section>
        <TopAnimateBlock numOfLine={2}>
          <TextStyle color="grey">mimicking</TextStyle>
          <TextStyle color="white">apple's design</TextStyle>
        </TopAnimateBlock>
      </Section>
      <Section>
        <BottomAnimateBlock numOfLine={1} delayTopLine={2}>
          <TextStyle color="white">for the win!</TextStyle>
        </BottomAnimateBlock>
      </Section>
    </Box>
</>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can broadly find 2 issues in the code:

First is this statement:

```
 const containerRef = useRef<IntersectionObserver | null>(null);
```

The implementation of the generic [`useRef`](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/hooks/#useref) is being done with `IntersectionObserver | null`. This indicates that the ref container will hold either an instance of `IntersectionObserver` or `null`. But instead the `ref` is being used with a `Box` element, (for those not versed with material-UI, this will be something similar to a `div`).

This statement could be changed to something like:

```
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
```

Second, the return type of the hook is not declared and TS auto detects it to be an array by looking at what is being returned (`[containerRef, isVisible]`). The type inferred by Typescript becomes:

[image: Typescript return type for the hook]

`(boolean | React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | null>)[]`. This means that the return type is an array of elements each can have one of the above 3 mentioned types.

Since the type is actually a `tuple` and both the returned array elements are of different types (known to us before hand), the type inferred is incorrect and TS complains.

**Explicitly declaring** this while defining the hook would prevent Typescript from complaining.

```
const useOnScreen = <T,>(options : T): [MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | null>, boolean] => {
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  const callbackFunction = (entries : : IntersectionObserverEntry[]) => {
    const [entry] = entries;
    setIsVisible(entry.isIntersecting);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callbackFunction, options);

    if (containerRef.current) observer.observe(containerRef?.current);

    return () => {
      if (containerRef.current) observer.unobserve(containerRef?.current);
    };
  }, [containerRef, options]);

  return [containerRef, isVisible];
};
```

A [link](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-function-return-type-tuple) explaining the difference between tuple return type and array return type.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, I need to go through it carefully to understand all :) A quick test and indeed the errors are gone. Only the 
const callbackFunction = (entries) => is throwing an error that entries has an any type. A quick test with declaring it as any all works. But this was just for testing purpose, what would be the correct type for entries in this case?

Comment: If you are using a decent code editor, you can go into the declarations file to find the type out. Find out what `new IntersectionObserver` expects as first param. That is the type you are looking for for callbackFunction` right. That is how i did it.

Comment: Did not know that thanks for the great help,  I worked on the code a bit further to remove another warning and got to a point where I am not sure if my solution is decent. Would you mind to take a look at this new Question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73085745/variable-from-inside-react-hook-useeffect-will-be-lost-after-each-render
I will award the bounty to you once its possible.

Comment: @Figario done from my end.